# Robolectric clicking view under unit test is possible?

Tags: android-espresso, robolectric

Asserting View's text using `Espresso` succeed but `perform(click())` seems didn't work.

My test code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [28])
class MainActivityTestRobo2 {


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    fun `test11`() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MainFragment>()
        scenario.recreate()
        onView(withId(R.id.button1)).check(matches(withText("Button1")))  // success
        onView(withId(R.id.message)).check(matches(withText("MainFragment")))  // success
        onView(withId(R.id.button1)).perform(click())  // maybe not worked!
        onView(withId(R.id.message)).check(matches(withText("Button1")))  // fail
    }

}
```

Because that `click()` should have changed `message`'s text to `Button1` from `MainFragment`.
By the way, I wrote test code under `test` not under `androidTest`.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tstester"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.2.3"


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Error message:

> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError:
>   'with text: is "Button1"' doesn't match the selected view. Expected:
>   with text: is "Button1"
>        Got: "TextView{id=2131165295, res-name=message, visibility=VISIBLE, width=12, height=41, has-focus=false,
>   has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@2673904a,
>   tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false,
>   x=154.0, y=191.0, **text=MainFragment**, input-type=0,
>   ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
>
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.postAsynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:312)
>     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:294)
>     ... 17 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 255